How to assign jobs on all core/threads on dual socket cpus in openmpi
I'm running an MPI program on a Dual Socket EPYC server with a total of 128 cores and 256 threads (two EPYC 9754). When using the mpiexec command processing using np=32 to run the processes at four times, I observe that on a Threadripper system (3990x), all 128 threads are automatically activated.
import subprocess

for _ in range(4):
    subprocess.Popen("mpiexec -np 32 process.py", shell=True)

But on the EPYC server, I can't seem to activate more than 128 threads, even if I increase the number of executions to 8 or greater. I think there is binding problem..
import subprocess
n_worker = 8
for _ in range(n_worker):
    subprocess.Popen("mpiexec -np 32 process.py", shell=True)

I used mpiexec (OpenRTE) 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
In my machine, this code returns
import multiprocessing
import psutil

print(f"Multiprocessing      : {multiprocessing.cpu_count()}")
print(f"psutil logical cores : {psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)}")
print(f"psutil physical cores: {psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)}")

Multiprocessing      : 512
psutil logical cores : 512
psutil physical cores: 256
I tried --oversubscribe and --use-hwthread-cpus options, but it did not works.
Currently, I manually assign jobs to each cpu using cpu-set
mpiexec --cpu-set 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 -np 32 --use-hwthread-cpus --oversubscribe process.py
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
